# Formatting 45.22.30 in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, validation

When copy and pasting value 45.22.30 for example in a textbox, what can be the best formatting code to remove the middle dot in the decimal value?

Comment: What will be the *middle dot* of two dots in your example?

Comment: The first dot between 5 and 2, so my desired output is 4,522.30

Comment: You will need so more examples of possible valid input: Could there be `4522.30` and `66.45.22.30` as well?

Comment: When I entered a number it must be like a numerical number that do not accept special characters except for a dot and comma. It will not accept also another dot to validate the input number.

Comment: Possible strategy: Replace last `.` with arbitrary delimiter (like `|`) then replace all remaining `.` with `string.Empty` then `Decimal.TryParseExact()` for your custom format picture.

Comment: If you can rely on a limited set of format pictures, you should be able to `.TryParseExact()` until success.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are helpful!

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour]